# Migrating project to null safety not achieved

Tags: flutter

I am trying to migrate an old Flutter project to Null Safety.

There is a ListView.builder where I get the list items from a API.

This is the old code:

```
 Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    child: FutureBuilder(
                      future: fetchClinicas(miId),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        print("SNAPSHOT   " + snapshot.hasData.toString());

                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          return ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                              print(index.toString());
                              Clinica clinica = snapshot.data[index];
```

Using the same code in my new app, there are a couple of errors.

First error at line

```
itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
```

The error output for the first error is:

```
The property 'length' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'
```

I have changed the line with

```
itemCount: snapshot.data?.length,
```

But the error is not gone.

And the second error is at line

```
Clinica clinica = snapshot.data[index];
```

The error output for the second error is

```
The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'
```

I have changed this second line with

```
Clinica clinica = snapshot.data![index];
```

but the error is not gone.

I would like to know how to make the code Null Safety compliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the migration tool which will migrate your codes easily.  Check this for reference

https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide

Also for the issues that you are facing on each error if you hover on it, it should show a suggestion to add a null check operator ! Or ?  Please note if you add an exclamation mark it means that the data is not null and if you add a ? It means that the data can be null or may have a value in it.

```
Clinica? clinica = snapshot.data![index'];
```

You can add a ? After the datatype which would mention that clinica can be null too. You may get other errors of you add a ? Here please make sure you add clinica! Wherever you use this variable